# Is it possible to add an if statement in a gulpfile that would run a task based on filesize?

Tags: javascript, arrays, npm, gulp

I'm using gulp to compress images, but I only want to compress images that are over 200kb in size. Is it possible to in JavaScript to go through a folder and only run the minification on files over 200kb? I'm using the lossy-imagemin package. As far as I know it'd only work with server-side language but I would like a definitive answer if possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what gulp lib are you using for it?

Comment: I'm pretty new to gulp so I'm not sure what a library is? But I'm using lossy-imagemin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/lossy-imagemin) for the images if that's what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible client-side.  This example uses [gulp-filter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-filter) to filter out files not greater than 200kb.

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const filter = require('gulp-filter');
const fs = require('fs');
//  const path = require('path');  not needed for this example
const someImageMin = require('  your image min plugin   ' );


gulp.task('default', function () {

  // include only files > 200KB
  // retore option needed if you want to reinject the filtered-out files later
  const myFilter = filter(file => (fs.statSync(file.path).size > 200000), {restore: true});

  return gulp.src(['pics/*jpg' , 'pics/*png'])
    .pipe(myFilter)
    .pipe(someImageMin())

     // if you want to reinject the files excluded by the filter
    .pipe(myFilter.restore)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('new'));
});

[gulp-ignore][2] is another option.
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a go.